# I am getting a error in node js which is of Require Stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

Getting this error in nodejs while trying to open .js file

{
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: }

Don't know what's causing this
Reinstalled node js along with it's packages and removed nodejs modules and added them again but still no success
Found solutions on some websites(including stackoverflow) but none of them seems to work

Answer (score 1):

This question requires more context, but here's how to think about solving the question. Whenever you have a 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' error, the culprit is almost always your package.json file.

Whatever code you're implementing in your `.js` depends on an npm module/package that is referenced in package.json, but (possibly) hasn't been installed (ie, there's no corresponding `node_modules` folder for the problem.

It's a bit odd that the require stack is empty, as that would have given us some insight into the problem.

Consider doing as I've described:

- Review the error and see if you can find anything in the require stack pointing to the issue.
- Check your package.json for all installed packages
- To be doubly sure, re-run `npm install`
- Make sure your JS file is in the same directory as the package.json file

Let me know how this goes!